# ember file uploader for all browser

Tags: ember.js, jquery-plugins, filereader, jquery-file-upload, ember-cli

I use FileReader to upload file in ember, using ember view . but it doesn't work in old browsers. what should I use for this case? may be [jquery file uploader](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) and should I write views for every input?